# What is the purpose of direct sums in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I had a course in linear algebra in which the concept of direct sum was presented. At first, it does not seems too complicated, there were some exercises to identify if things are or aren't direct sums but there was nothing beyond that. So, why are they important?

I know that summing a vector from a vector space and a vector from another vector space in which these vector spaces share only the $0$ vector will give me a new vector space but I guess I could create this notion (creating new vector spaces) only by talking of linear combinations.

Comment: For one, direct sums are secretly what make block matrix multiplication work.

Comment: They are also the means of getting your hands on the orthogonal complement, if you have an inner product. If $V$ is a vector space, and $W$ and vector subspace, there is another subspace $C$ so that $V = W \oplus C$, i.e. every vector in $V$ can be written as something in $W$ plus something orthogonal to $W$. Perhaps obvious, but not so obvious in infinite dimensions, and still a fundamental result.

Comment: For one more, one of the reasons of the fact that bases are important is the fact that you can decompose vectors uniquely in terms of them. A direct sum also does it. You can decompose vectors uniquely in terms of elements of each space.

Comment: They might seem kind of unnecessary in linear algebra, but in other fields, like abstract algebra, analysis and topology, it becomes much less so. Don't get me wrong, it still works the same way, intuitively, but the resulting constructions aren't quite so... trivial. Linear algebra is a good place to get used to them.